# How to print alphabet of ascii value

Tags: java, char, type-conversion, int, java.util.scanner

Actually I wanted output like that now 
    eg:
    Enter the digit
     66
     67
     68
     69
     convert
     66-A
     67-B
     68-C
     69-D

i am getting output like this 
    66 
    66-A
    67
    67-B
    68
    68-C

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n + "-" + (char) c);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the `variable c` is in your code.
Anyway, I think you should print it after the input is finished.

```java
int[] arr = new int[4];

// You only need to create it once.
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
}

// When input is finished, output contents.
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i] + "-" + (char) arr[i]);
}
```

#### input:

> 65
>   66
>   67
>   68

#### output:

> 65-A
>   66-B
>   67-C
>   68-D

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n + "-" + (char) n);
}
sc.close();
```

Note:

1. There is no need to create a new *Scanner* object everytime the loop
   executes. Declare it once outside the loop and re-use it.
2. You need to convert `n` to `char` and print it.